# How does maven knows which plugin needs to invoke from the goal?

Tags: java, maven

Let's say

when you call `mvn archetype:generate` how does maven knows that it needs to invoke "Maven Archetype Plugin"?

Or when you do `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` how does it invoke 'Apache Maven Dependency Plugin'?

i.e How does maven maintains the link between 'archetype' -> 'Maven Archetype Plugin'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's available by default. This page lists the core plugins and others

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/.

If you want to use other plugin, you need to mention in pom.xml file, so that the dependencies can be resolved.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--Restdocs config for collating all snippets start-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>XXX</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

If you run the command `mvn animal-sniffer:check`. `animal-sniffer` is the plugin prefix and `check` is the goal. The mapping between prefix and dependency is mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html). Meanwhile, the goal `check` is mapped by annotation in actual implementation, if you check the source code of this plugin, you will see something like below.

```
@Mojo( name = "check", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_CLASSES, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE, threadSafe = true )
```

Comment: What if they are not default?

Comment: if they are not default, you need to mention in `<build><plugins><plugin> ...` tag in pom.xml. So they maven will download dependencies accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, when we specify <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId> ... how does it know it should use this plugin when I issue 'mvn animal-sniffer:check'? the name (animal-sniffer) is not refered as-is anywhere.

Comment: Normally, you can run mvn by using `mvn  <plugin-prefix>:<goal>`, so in this case, plugin-prefix is `animal-sniffer`. Internally, maven resolved the prefix following the login mentioned in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html. If you check the pom.xml of this plugin, you will see this line <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>. Hope it clarifies now.